# Understanding NginX's proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I'm looking for advice on how to simplify a problem so that I can understand it fully, and discover how to troubleshoot it.

I have followed the DigitalOcean [tutorial on installing Meteor on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-meteor-js-application-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-nginx), using a Desktop version of Ubuntu in a virtual machine, and using SSH just as if it were a server. I have succeeded in installing NginX and viewing a static page served by NginX on the virtual machine from my host computer, using a rewrite rule to enforce the HTTPS protocol:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/my_app.net/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name my_app.net;

    # redirect non-SSL to SSL
    location / {
        rewrite     ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
    }
}
```

I have also succeeding in installing all the other dependencies and getting the Meteor bundle to run. When I open Firefox in the Ubuntu VM, and visit `localhost:8080`, I can see that Meteor is running fine.

However, when I connect to the VM server from a browser in my host machine, I still see the static page, not the Meteor page.

The config file for the Meteor site contains these settings:

```
# HTTPS server
server {
    listen 443 ssl spdy;
    server_name my_app.net;

    # ... more stuff ...

    # pass all requests to Meteor
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; # allow websockets
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr; # preserve client IP

        # this setting allows the browser to cache the application in a way compatible with Meteor
        # on every applicaiton update the name of CSS and JS file is different, so they can be cache infinitely (here: 30 days)
        # the root path (/) MUST NOT be cached
        if ($uri != '/') {
            expires 30d;
        }
    }
}
```

(Full version [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-meteor-js-application-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-nginx#step-1-%E2%80%94-setting-up-an-nginx-web-server))

I'm not a fan of cargo cult programming: I prefer to understand any code that I copy and paste from a tutorial.

I understand that the line `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080` is intended to map the output that I can see internally in `localhost:8080` to the HTTPS port 443.

Now, I'd like to remove the Meteor site from the equation (since that part is working). I'd like to create a bare-bones set-up using a static HTML page that is served to `127.0.0.1:8080`, so that I can understand how the proxy_pass feature passes the page on to port 443.

How should I set up the config file to display a simple HTML page internally at `localhost:8080` and externally at `https://my_meteor_app.net`?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new server block that listens to port 8080 and serves static files out of some directory:

```
server {
    listen 8080;

    root /var/www/temporary/site;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # redirect non-SSL to SSL
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/;
    }
}
```

Assuming you do not change your ssl termination block (listening to 443 and proxy passing to 127.0.0.1:8080), then the above block should work both locally and deployed to your domain.